# How to remove focus from wxTextCtrl in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I am using `wxEVT_SET_FOCUS` for `wxTextCtrl` in `wxWidgets`. What I need to do is when user clicks textctrl I have to open a new window and remove focus from textctrl so that FocusHandler function will be executed only once. Is there any function to remove focus from `wxTextCtrl` ?

```
Using this connect event in constructor
//Connect Events
m_passwordText->Connect(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, wxFocusEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPasswordTextBoxSetFocus), NULL, this);


 void MyFrame::OnPasswordTextBoxSetFocus(wxFocusEvent& event)
 {
       if(some condition is true)
           //code to open a new window

       event.Skip()
       // is there any option to remove focus from password textCtrl so that once a new window opens
       //I can remove focus from password and avoid executing this function again and again.
       // If new window opens for the first time, I perform the operation and close it
       // then also it opens again as control is still in password textbox. 
       //Is there any way to resolve this?
 }
```

Basically I want to stop multiple executions of handler function once the new window is opened without disconnecting the wxeVT_SET_FOCUS from wxTextCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the control gains or looses the focus a focus event is fired, and your handler comes into action.

There are some causes for this focus event. The most cumbersome is when the new window is created and deleted, because it may generate its own focus events, and your handler may deal with them all. There's a *reentrance* issue.

We deal with reentrance using a flag, which tell us if we are in a reentrance case.

```
void MyFrame::OnPasswordTextBoxSetFocus(wxFocusEvent& event)
{
    static bool selfFired = false; //our flag

    event.Skip(); //always allows default processing for focus-events

    if ( event.GetEventType() == wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS )
    {
         //Nothing to do. Action takes place with wxEVT_SET_FOCUS
         return;
    }

    //Deal with re-entrance
    if ( !selFired )
    {
         if (some condition)
         {
              selfFired = true;

              //Open a new window.
              //Pass 'this' to its ctor (or similar way) so that new window
              //is able to SetFocus() back to this control
              newWin = open a window...

              newWin->SetFocus(); //this may be avoided if the new window gains focus on its own
         }
    }
    else
    {
        //restore the flag
        selfFired = false;
    }
}
```